# What is max size of a single zip object stored in S3 bucket, as a result of a dynamo db export process?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

When I'm exporting DynamoDb to S3, choosing json objects as an output, then I'm ending up having a bunch of json zip files in my S3 bucket.

I don't know and I didn't find anything about an existing limitation for the size of the zip file.

Do you know if there is any limitation? Maybe the limitation will be the maximum size for a json file?

I'm really interested how AWS "decide" to zip the data from dynamoDb, because the zip files have different size.

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB optimizes the export procedure by parallelizing it, resulting in the generation of multiple files in your designated S3 bucket. Although there's no specified maximum file size, individual files usually hover around 128MB. The size variability stems from attribute diversity, compression efficiency, and the number of items within the exported segment. In some cases you may even have empty files exported.

I'm avoiding the actual specifics of how DynamoDB implements the export logic, as its largely implementation detail and is subject to change.

To summarise, the number of files you receive depends on the number of segments DynamoDB use to parallelize the export, this is non configurable.